# Help with Matlab commands?

Tags: matlab

The body's surface area is often using for determining doses of drugs. It's not
easy to measure a person's surface area, so there have been various formulae proposed to
estimate the surface area using a person's height and weight. Three formulae for the body
surface area in m^2 are:

- Mosteller: sqrt hw/3600
- du Bois and du Bois: 0:007184 h^0725 w^0.425
- Haycock: 0:024265 h^0.3964 w^0.5378

where h is the height measured in centimetres and w the weight in kilogrammes.

How would I go about using Matlab to calculate the body surface area using each of the formulae for a person whose height is 170 cm and whose weight is 75 kg? What Matlab commands should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clear all

h = 170;

w = 75;

M = sqrt(h*w/3600)

B = 0.007184*h^(0.725)*w^(0.425)

H = 0.024265*h^(0.3964)*w^(0.5378)

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @LauraAnderson You're welcome.